# Laravel 5 correct permissions, still failing

Tags: laravel-5, directory, storage, permission-denied, selinux

As per numerous references online, Laravel documentation, and scouring answers here on SO, I am a bit baffled as to why I have set my directory permissions precisely as expected, but still am getting "Permission Denied" fatals.

I have applied the following to the storage & bootstrap/cache directories.

```
chown -R apache:apache storage bootstrap/cache
chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

Just shy of being a total security idiot and 777'ing those directories...which I will **NOT** do. (So, please do not even bother offering that as a suggestion!) I'm at a loss for what could still be wrong here.

Anyone else dealt with this?

**GAME CHANGER UPDATE**
NOTE: I just discovered the cause. Which drastically changes the scope of this question now. It seems that selinux was the issue. When I did setenforce 0, this fixed the problem.

So, now the question is what do I need to do in selinux to make this work without disabling selinux entirely?

Answer (score 0):

Okay...so, it seems that the answer lies in setting up selinux to allow apache to have rw access to directories. (*All commands ran as root*)

First, run this command (assuming an OS of RHEL/Centos);

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /path/to/web/root
```

Then make that change persistent with this command;

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/path(/.*)?"
```

This fixed my problem!

Solution found here;
[SELinux Apache Setup for Web Servers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50639/httpd-cant-write-to-folder-file-because-of-selinux)